# Unable to get route param from chrome extension url in angular

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, angular-router

I'm using angular to develop a chrome extension and when I attempt to get a route param from a url I am not getting anything. I know another route I can go about this, but do any of you know why it's not working the way it's supposed to?

Here's the url... As you can see the param is there.

[image]

```
ngOnInit() {
    // Collect params from the url
    var nextRoute = null;
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      nextRoute = params['redirectTo'];
      console.log(nextRoute);
    });
```

nextRoute is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not totally sure but as i see `redirectTo` is a query param and if you want to grab it you might come up with the follwing

```
 this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            console.log(params);
        });
```

The above will console the `JSON` object of your query params then you can grab your data

#### a simple note

Use the snapshot for a one-time grab or a subscription if the parameters can change within the same component/route
`this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')`